# Change the cycle order in a three state Checkbox in javafx

Tags: javafx, checkbox

Is there a way to change the click order for the three-state Checkbox in javafx?
The default is check->uncheck->indeterminate.
Is it possible to instead have the following order? check->indeterminate->uncheck ?

Some background on the why.

The app that uses the checkbox defaults the checkbox to false which corresponds to a process that needs to be but hasn't yet been checked.
The undefined state corresponds to a process that was physically checked and has been determined as bad.
 The checked state corresponds to a process that was physically checked and has passed QC.
 The true cases occur more often than the undefined cases.

Since the default is false, the next click cycled to is undefined. (bad) and then true(check). These clicks are made for several process and changing the order will considerably reduce the number of clicks that has to be made by the user.

Comment: hmm ... you would confuse your users, so why would you want that?

Comment: As kleopatra says, that would be confusing for users and a poor design choice in most cases. However, you may need to set up a click listener for the `CheckBox` and set the state yourself.

Comment: The app that uses the checkbox defaults the box to false which corresponds to a process that needs to be but hasn't been checked. The undef state is  a process that was physically checked and has been determined as bad. The  checked state is a process that was physically checked and has passed QC The true cases occur more often than the undefined cases. Since the default is false, the next click cycled to is undefined. (bad) and then true(check). These clicks are made for several process and changing the order will considerably reduce the number the clicks that has to be made by the user.

Comment: thanks for the explanation (which you might consider editing into your question :) Hmm ... maybe a custom control might be a better option? Something that doesn't allow so much cycling but a single transition from not-physically-checked to either physically-checked-and-okay or physically-checked-and-bad?

Comment: hmm... wondering why you don't revise the logic to fit into the model of the checkbox: checkBox.indeterminate (or not defined) == physically-not-checked, checkBox.selected == physically-checked-and-good, checkBox.unselected== physically-checked-and-bad Then start out with indetermined and the toggle cycle is as you need it

Comment: @kleopatra I have edited the question. Like you suggest I will try changing the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for helping me with your suggestions. I have now found an answer to this problem.
The cycling of the order in the CheckBox class is based on the following logic
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/CheckBox.html

```
checked: indeterminate == false, checked == true
unchecked: indeterminate == false, checked == false
undefined: indeterminate == true
```

I created an extension to the CheckBox class and overrode the fire() method
Below is the version of the CheckBox which now cycles as required.

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;

/**
 *
 * @author returncode13
 */
public class RcheckBox extends CheckBox{


    /**
     * Toggles the state of the {@code CheckBox}. If allowIndeterminate is
     * true, then each invocation of this function will advance the CheckBox
     * through the states checked, undefined, and unchecked. If
     * allowIndeterminate is false, then the CheckBox will only cycle through
     * the checked and unchecked states, and forcing indeterminate to equal to
     * false.
     */

    @Override
    public void fire() {
        super.fire(); 
        if(!isDisabled()){

            if(isAllowIndeterminate()){
                 if(!isSelected() && !isIndeterminate()){
                    setIndeterminate(true);
                }else if(isIndeterminate()){
                    setSelected(true);
                    setIndeterminate(false);
                }else if(isSelected() && !isIndeterminate()){
                    setSelected(false);
                    setIndeterminate(false);
                }
            }else{
                setSelected(!isSelected());
                setIndeterminate(false);
            }
            fireEvent(new ActionEvent());


        }
    }

}
```